# How do I get a beautiful image overlay from data and a model function?

Tags: plotting, image, legending

I have a set of experimental [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlvq8mlcwpylhql/forcemapf.xls?dl=0) that I wish to make into a density plot. Then I have to overlay an image of a model function `f(x, y, z) = Sin(x/z)Sin(y)` on the density image such that parameters `a, b` and `w are used to control the size and position of the model image on the density image. 
I actually succeeded halfway as shown in the following code:

```
canto = Import["forcemapf.xls"];
ListDensityPlot[canto, Axes -> False, Frame -> False]
```

This produce [image1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpo9gfid3g4fb12/comton.jpg?dl=0). I now used comton in:

```
Manipulate[
  ImageCompose[
    comton,
    ImageResize[
      ColorReplace[
        Image[
          DensityPlot3D[Sin[x/z] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
            Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue]], 
        White -> Transparent], 
      s]], 
  {s, 50, 300, 1}]
```

However, I still got the following problems

1. I currently have only `s` (controlling the size of the model image) and could not get the other control parameters to work.
2. I would love to use `ListPlotDensity` after `ImageCompose` instead of an image (comton). I am not really sure if this is even possible.
3. I wish to have legend (probably using `PlotLegends`) of the model function `f(x, y, z)` placed by the right hand side. I tried several methods but still did not succeed; one of the methods gave the legend but the model image disappeared. Another method meanwhile worked with the image overlay but the legend did work with `ImageCompose`.
4. I could not use other control parameters (`w, a` and `b`) unless the objects are certain types of images. My attempt is as follows (image2 is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/shsl8vv69t1kmr5/comtona.jpg?dl=0)):

   Manipulate[
     ImageCompose[
       comton,
       ImageResize[
         ColorReplace[comtona, White -> Transparent], 
         White -> Transparent, 
         w], 
       {a, b}], 
     {w, 50, 300, 1}, 
     {a, 50, 130,10}, 
     {b, 50, 130, 10}]

I would be grateful if you guys can help in checking out where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: Does the data `canto` match the set of 3D points `{x,y,z}`?

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks. canto represent a 3D data imported to be plotted. It has nothing to do with 3D points {x,y,z}; these points are for the function f(x,y,z)=Sin(x/z)Sin(y)!

Comment: Then the data should look like `{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}`